# html/css on hover - add padding bottom not moving rest of elements

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I am trying to do like tabs (I am not sure how to call them). When a tab is hovered, it increases the padding-bottom for that tab (visually it looks like it comes up).

Those, will sit on the top of the navigation, so I have placed them at the bottom of the header.

The problem is, it moves all the tabs! not just the one I am hovering. I have been changing position absolute/relative and adding/removing the .actionsWrap div, but nothing works as I expect. Also, the container of those need to be positioned absolute to the header.

Can someone see what am I doing wrong? See the jsfiddle attached, as you can see what I mean much easier.

https://jsfiddle.net/0yu921xp/

**html**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="actionsWrap">
            <div class="actions">
                <div><a class="search fa fa-2x fa-search" href="" alt="" title=""></a></div>
                <div><a class="help fa fa-2x fa-question" href="" alt="" title=""></a></div>
                <div><a class="call fa fa-2x fa-phone" href="" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="logo" src="ttp://res.cloudinary.com/demo/ image/upload/ w_133,h_133,c_thumb,g_face/ bike.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</header>
```

**css**

```
header 
{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

header .actionsWrap 
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
}

header .actionsWrap .actions 
{
    position: relative; 
}

header .actionsWrap .actions div 
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50px; 
}

header .actionsWrap .actions div a 
{
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block; 
}

header .actionsWrap .actions div a:hover 
{
    padding-bottom: 30px; 
}

header .actionsWrap .actions .search 
{
    color: khaki;
    background-color: darkcyan; 
}

header .actionsWrap .actions .help 
{
    color: darkblue;
    background-color: lightblue; 
}

header .actionsWrap .actions .call 
{
    color: yellowgreen;
    background-color: bisque; 
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `float` on those elements you can't control the vertical alignment, one option is use `inline-block` instead:

```
header .actionsWrap .actions div {
   position: relative;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-right:-4px;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   width: 50px; 
}
```

#### [Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0yu921xp/1/)

Comment: answer for thumbs up

Comment: so.... I am not allowed to do this sort of things (negative margins to solve inline-block space between elements), however, it seems it is the one best works so I will keep it, just in case :)

Comment: np mate there is other ways to solve the sapce between inline-blocks just for a quick answer i use it here @eve_mf glad to help u

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline` property to `<a>`, like:

```
header .actionsWrap .actions div a:hover {
  display: inline;
}
```

Have a look at the updated **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yu921xp/3/)** or snippet below:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
  header .actionsWrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; }
    header .actionsWrap .actions {
      position: relative; }
      header .actionsWrap .actions div {
        position: relative;
        float: left; }
        header .actionsWrap .actions div a {
          padding: 15px;
          text-align: center;
          display: block; }
          header .actionsWrap .actions div a:hover {
            padding-bottom: 30px; display: inline; }
      header .actionsWrap .actions .search {
        color: khaki;
        background-color: darkcyan; }
      header .actionsWrap .actions .help {
        color: darkblue;
        background-color: lightblue; }
      header .actionsWrap .actions .call {
        color: yellowgreen;
        background-color: bisque; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="actionsWrap">
         <div class="actions">
           <div><a class="search fa fa-2x fa-search" href="" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            <div><a class="help fa fa-2x fa-question" href="" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            <div><a class="call fa fa-2x fa-phone" href="" alt="" title=""></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <img class="logo" src="ttp://res.cloudinary.com/demo/ image/upload/ w_133,h_133,c_thumb,g_face/ bike.jpg" alt=""/>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok... I can't see why it doesn't do it in your snippet but it does in my code, the display: inline makes the anchor not to be the 50px width of the div. But I will play with it from here!

Thank you

Comment: I am going to accept DaniP answer, as although it is not ideal because my team requirements, it is the one that works best and smooth. Yours behave as I wanted, but it changes the with of the buttons

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: ADDED A SECOND SOLUTION

1.) To have the addition space extend belos the border of the container:

Change the position of `.actionsWrap` from `bottom: 0` to `top:138px` to anchor its top border to the top of its container instead of the bottom border to the bottom of the container:

```
header .actionsWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 138px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wn0ndeca/1/

2.) To have the bottom borders of the three elements still aligned at the bottom border of the container on hover:

Change the display of `.actions div` to `inline-blocks` with `vertical-align: bottom;`

```
header .actionsWrap .actions div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 50px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qqghpuj3/1/

(note the slighty changed HTML code to avois whitespace between the three elements)

Comment: The height of the header changes, as it is responsive, I have added a height of 200px but in the real project I do not have height for it. However, it does the job so thanks

Comment: then you could use `top: calc(100% - 62px;)`

Comment: please note my second solution (I wasn't sure which way you actually wanted the DIVs to extend)